# Does an unbounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ contain infinitely many multiples of some number?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $U$ is an unbounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, does there exist some $a$ such that infinitely many integer multiples of $a$ belong to U?

Comment: I assume you only want integer multiples?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: I would think yes, using the Baire category theorem (or better yet Cantor intersection) but hazy about the details. The idea, for each open set $V$ find suitable $n_V$ and intersect all $\frac V{n_V}$. That is, all $V$'s are disjoint open sets contained in $U$ and "going to $\infty$", and we may assume the closure of each $V$ is compact and contained in $U$. But, there may be some "compatibility" issues finding simultaneously suitable $n_V$ and $n_W$ for different $V,W$. Well, someone posted an answer let me stop speculating.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can flesh out your ideas.

Comment: wow, two answers posted quickly, one yes one no, both also gone quickly :)

Comment: I can't help but wonder if quotienting $\Bbb R$ by $a\Bbb Z$ for $a\in\Bbb R$ (all the integer multiples of $a$) would help since that would be homomorphic to the unit circle, then using the quotient topology you might be able to simplify your problem since the unit circle is compact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $I_1 = (a,b)$ be some interval of positive numbers contained in the set $S$. Consider the union of its multiples, save for $I_1$ itself: $$U_1 := \bigcup_{n = 2}^{\infty} n \cdot I_1.$$ You can check that there exist an $N_1$ so that for all $x \geq N_1$, $x \in U_1$. As $S$ is unbounded, there must exist an $x_1 \in S \cap U_1$. Therefore, $x_1$ will be element of some $n_1 \cdot I_1$. Let $I_2$ be an interval containing $x_1$ in $I_2 \subset (n_1 \cdot I_1) \cap S$. All numbers in $I_2$ are multiples by $n_1$ of numbers in $I_1$.

Define $$U_2 := \bigcup_{n = 2}^{\infty} n \cdot I_2.$$ Again there exists an $N_2$ so that for all $x \geq N_2$, $x \in U_2$. As $S$ is unbounded, there must exist an $x_2 \in S \cap U_2$. $x_2$ will be element of some $n_2 \cdot I_2$. Let $I_3$ be an interval containing $x_2$ and subset of  $I_3 \subset (n_2 \cdot I_2) \cap S$. All numbers in $I_3$ are multiples by $n_2$ of numbers in $I_2$, and therefore multiples by $n_1 \cdot n_2$ of numbers in $I_1$.

Continue this construction inductively, so that all $I_n$ consist of multiples of all intervals preceding them in the sequence.

We now reduce these intervals $I_n$ to *compact*, *closed* intervals $J_n$ by $(a, b) \mapsto [a + \frac{(b-a)}{3}, b - \frac{(b-a)}{3}]$, i.e. the inner third of the interval. The desired properties from above concerning multiples still hold.

Now, by the axiom of choice, determine a sequence $y_n \in J_n$. Divide it to get a sequence in $J_1$: $$z_n := \frac{y_n}{\prod_{i = 1}^{n - 1} n_i}.$$

As it is a sequence in a compact, closed and bounded interval, it has a converging subsequence $\sigma$. Its limit, $Z$, lies in $J_1$, but also in $\frac{1}{n_1} J_2$, in $\frac{1}{n_1 \cdot n_2} J_3$ and so forth, as $\sigma$, save for some initial terms, lies completely in  $\frac{1}{n_1} J_2$, in $\frac{1}{n_1 \cdot n_2} J_3$ and so forth. Therefore, infinitely many multiples of $Z$ lie in $S$.

(I hope someone can come up with a more elegant proof, but brute force works sometimes...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, as far as I can see, this is correct. I'll look at it a bit more carefully before accepting.

Comment: I haven't spent too much time here, but it looks like you have a nested sequence of closed intervals $J_1 \supset \frac{1}{n_1}J_2 \supset\ldots$ - and saying that the intersection of those intervals is non-empty doesn't require choice (...though it looks like your construction of them requires some weaker forms of choice) - non-emptiness follows from compactness of closed intervals.

Answer (score 10):

You can prove this using the Baire category theorem. Let's let $U$ be an unbounded subset of the positive reals, noting that this change does not affect the theorem. Define $U_n = U \cap (n,\infty)$ and define
$$V_n = \{x\in\mathbb R^+ : \text{There exists an integer }k\text{ so that }kx\in U_n\}.$$
This set is open as we could also write
$$V_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}kU_n$$
where each of the sets in the union is open.

We note that $V_n$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$ because its complement cannot contain any intervals - note that if an interval $(a,a+\varepsilon)$ was in the complement of $V_n$, then, $U_n$ must be disjoint from every interval of the form $(ka, ka+k\varepsilon)$. However, the union $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(ka,ka+k\varepsilon)$ has a bounded complement in $\mathbb R^+$ because for any $k$ such that $k\varepsilon > a$, the interval $(ka,ka+k\varepsilon)$ overlaps with $((k+1)a, (k+1)a+(k+1)\varepsilon)$ and thus this union contains all of $(ka,\infty)$. Since $U$ is unbounded, this cannot be.

Note that the set of numbers for which there are infinitely many multiples in $U$ is exactly
$$\mathscr V=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n$$
since if there were only finitely many multiples of $x$ in $U$, then there would be none in some $U_n$. This is a countable intersection of open dense sets in $[0,\infty)$. By the Baire category theorem, $\mathscr V$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$ - and, in particular, it is not empty.

Comment: Do you mean $(n,\infty)$ in the third line?

Comment: @Jehu314 Yes, fixed it.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This develops an idea posted in an answer by @lulu, since deleted (before I could grasp the details, so @lulu is not responsible for my possible misinterpretation :).
I am confused, so let me write a sketch of it before I forget it.

Assume $\sup U=\infty$. Define $a_1<b_1<a_2<b_2<\cdots$ and $n_1,n_2,\dots$ such that:

(i) $[a_k,b_k]\subset U$,
(ii) $\bigl(n_k\cdot(a_k,b_k)\bigr)\cap U\neq\emptyset$,
(iii) $[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\subset\bigl(n_k\cdot(a_k,b_k)\bigr)\cap U$.

Then $(a_k,b_k)\cap\frac U{n_k}\neq\emptyset$ and 
$\frac{[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]}{n_k}\subset(a_k,b_k)\cap\frac U{n_k}\subset[a_k,b_k]\subset U$.

Moreover, $\frac{[a_{k+2},b_{k+2}]}{n_k n_{k+1}}\subset\frac{(a_{k+1},b_{k+1})\cap U}{n_k}\subset\frac{[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]}{n_k}\subset U$.

Thus 
$\frac{[a_{k+2},b_{k+2}]}{n_k n_{k+1}}\subset\frac{[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]}{n_k}\subset
[a_k,b_k]\subset U$.

The idea is to "diagonalize" and get a nested sequence of closed intervals, 
$[a_1,b_1]\supseteq\frac{[a_2,b_2]}{n_1}\supseteq\frac{[a_3,b_3]}{n_1 n_2}\supseteq\cdots\supseteq\frac{[a_{1+j},b_{1+j}]}{n_1 n_1\cdots n_{j}}$. (Then take $a$ in their intersection.) I have to think more, but I will post this.

Comment: This seems very similar to my answer below. Making the intervals closed was crucial to determining an element which has multiples in *all* of the intervals.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof I saw you posted an answer before me, and it is reasonable to believe mine is similar. But I had started writing mine, and did not want to read yours, since that would risk me forgetting what I had. I need some time to digest the question and both answers.

Comment: Sure, go ahead - it wasn't meant as criticism of any kind. I also based myself on the idea by @lulu.