# Limit of real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to give an answer to an assignment question and I don't know where to start. I would prefer the direction of how to solve it instead of an explicit answer since I have no work done on it yet.

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that for each real number $x$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(nx)=0$. Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: you may make use of the following question and its answers https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3407107

Comment: This question was already asked and anwered here:
[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101086/lim-n-to-inftyfnx-0-implies-lim-x-to-inftyfx-0)